# why can the devil offer riches?

Tags: satan, temptation

Often people talk about the devil offering one all these material things if one should worship him.
People even believe that they can become rich and famous if they sell their soul, Why is this!?
The devil even tempted Christ with the wealth of all the nations.

Why can the devil do this? Why does he have all this "wealth" to offer?

Comment: You have a very interesting question, however I'm not sure that it's a good fit for the site in its [current form](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/1381#1381) (it is a truth seeking question).  You may want to reference scripture where the premise of your question comes from.  Also, you may want to narrow your scope to a specific denomination as I believe, there could be denominational based answers - which means no single correct answer.  I am going to -1 until the question is changed (or closed).

Comment: Do you not see this every day? Not a creature called “the devil” walking around making these offers, but people, organisations etc. (the devils servants). For we are the devils servants if we do the devils work, and gods servants if we do gods work.

Comment: I'm not sure what to suggest for this question, as it is a bit off, but I think we should let it go for now and see what answers we get. I would hope to see a good analyses of the relevant scriptures and quick discussion of "selling one's soul."

Comment: @fredsbend can salvation be lost? - rhetorical question

Comment: Tough to give a good answer when the question has been put on hold, but from the LDS perspective, who says the Devil has anything to offer in the first place?  He is, after all, the father of lies (2 Nephi 9:9; Ether 8:25; Moses 4:4)

Answer (score 4):

Here's the passage where Satan tempts Jesus in this way:

> **Matthew 4:8-10** Again, the devil took him to a very high mountain and showed him all the **kingdoms** of the world and their glory. And he said to him, “All these I will give you, if you will fall down and worship me.” Then Jesus said to him, “Be gone, Satan! For it is written, “‘You shall worship the Lord your God and him only shall you serve.’”

Notice how Satan is offering the **kingdoms** of the world, not the riches. Satan doesn't have banks of gold, but what he *can* do is lie and blind people to the truth.

> **2 Corinthians 4:3-4 ESV** And even if our gospel is veiled, it is veiled to those who are perishing. In their case **the god of this world** has blinded the minds of the unbelievers, to keep them from seeing the light of the gospel of the glory of Christ, who is the image of God.

He has a deceptive stranglehold on the evil rulers of the world and that is what he was offering to Jesus; *or at least what he was claiming to offer*.

Also, stories about people mystically "selling their soul" to the devil are pure fantasy tales and not in scripture, unless to "sell one's soul" just means to do evil and revel in it--a lot of that happens.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put, he is the ruler of this earth and has great influence. Revelations mentions that he was casted out of heaven with his demons (fallen angels) and was bound to the earth. 1 John 5:19 states that the whole world is lying in the power of the wicked one, otherwise known as the Devil, Satan.

Comment: Does "ruler of this earth" challenge the omnipotence of God?

Comment: @TheFreemason No, the devil can not challenge the omnipotence of God. (Job 1:7 and on, Satan asks permission to do things). The devil can only be 1 place at a time. Revelation 12:9, The devil and his angels are on earth and banned from Heaven. The devil ruled the earth for a time when he took mans authority over it in Eden, yet Jesus restored it to man (1 John 3:8). Also, the Devil knows his time is short (Revelation 12:12)

Comment: @JREAM please do not think that I disagree with you.  I am only stating that if Satan is the ruler of the earth, then how can God be omnipotent?  You're either omnipotent or not.  If God is omnipotent than Satan cannot be the ruler of the earth.

Comment: @the freemason, God is omnipotent and yet allows the devil a short season upon the earth. The devil is like a dog on a leash, he can only go as far as God will permit him

Comment: You just said a whole lot of words, none of which are scholarly, referenced, or consistent with what this site's intent is.  Your comment is very poetic, heart felt, and passionate and I commend you for it.  Being a good Christian doesn't always mean success on this site.  You assertion is that God gives control to the devil however God could change his mind at any second.  Allowing the devil to harm, lead away, and potentially destroy his prized creation.  Please supply references.

Comment: It says in Psalm 138:2 "..for you have magnified Your word above all Your name." -- God has put his word above his own name, meaning if he does not keep his word he would cease to be God. 

----

You can see that beginning in Ezekiel 28:13-19  
(1) Lucifer was created & inteded for Good
(2) He was the highest ranking Angel
(3) He became proud and wicked on account of his beauty

----

The question one must ask themselves now is: If the devil was an angel, and is now fallen -- Are angels omnipotent? 

Angels are Mighty in Strength (Psa 103:20) so they are powerful but not omnipotent.

Comment: @TheFreemason It's written that Satan is the god of this world/age (2 Cor 4:4), meaning he has quite an influence over unbelievers to those who give a foothold (Eph 4:27). The devil was never equal to God in the beginning (Ezekiel 28:13 ..). However, the devil does have a kingdom which are 1/3 of the fallen angels in the beginning (Rev 12:3-4). So one could think Satan Himself is attacking them, when it is not Satan himself, but one of the evil angels in his kingdom. I think you'd have to be a big influence for God to get Satan himself to come at you. Does that help?

Comment: @JREAM we'll need to break this into a separate chat.  Lucifer is not Satan nor the devil nor an angel.  "Lucifer" doesn't exist in the bible that I read - but it does in the KJV.  Don't forget that there are Cherubs and Seraphs - which are not angels.  Also, I agree with you and I ever said that angels are omnipotent.  If God is omnipotent then the devil or Satan can rule nothing.

Comment: @TheFreemason Yeah in some translations it might say "The morning star" rather than Lucifer. I know that Satan has angels (Matthew 25:41) -- So I am inclined to think he was the highest-ranking angel who recruited his "kind". I know Ezekiel 28.13 says he was a Cheribum (Which is a winged angels I read, if that's correct). Also Michael the Archangel fought the devil and his angels in heaven, so imagine a host of angels in battle and Satan being the only non-angel, it's strange to me anyways. I suppose then I'd ask, are Cherubs or Seraphs angels? I dont know myself for sure right now.

Comment: @TheFreemason I think you are looking at it differently. The devil/Satan can not interrupt mans free will -- nor can God. The devil is not the ruler of man kind in totality. The Bible does state: Do not love anything in the world, anyone who does the Fathers love in not in him. That doesnt mean the grass and pretty views, it means the world of sin/rebellion. So ultimately Satan nor God cannot do much unless there is an open door (foothold) by either Sin = Devil, Repentance = God.

Comment: In ALL translations,it says Morning Star - except the King James.  I agree, we are looking at this differently.